# Keep dataflow order when SSIS exports to flat file

Tags: ssis, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a database content to a flat file (csv) with SSIS. The export is pretty simple, since there is no modification in the dataflow, just a simple SQL request (Select, Where, order by ID), to a flat file.

Yet, there are more than 1 million lines in the requested export, and resulting file shows lines in incorrect order. Indeed, the file content has batches of (random) hundred lines  correctly sorted, but the file as whole is not sorted.

Quick example of IDs in the file:

- 103
- 104
- 105
- 106
- 122
- 123
- 124
- 117
- 118
- 119
- 107
- 108 ...

What I noticed/tried :

1. When I run my SQL request on management studio, it is sorted.
2. I tried to insert a "Sort" task between SQL command and export to flat file.
3. I set the bufferMaxRow to 1...
4. I am guessing it is a problem of buffering/writing in the file.

Comment: I assume you have an explicit sort in your SQL?  What version of SSIS?

Comment: Perhaps the following link will assist.  It discusses changing the IsSorted and SortKeyPosition property settings in the OLE DB source. http://www.ssistalk.com/2009/09/17/ssis-avoiding-the-sort-components/

Comment: Simple answer is SSIS is chunking the results and dealing with multiple threads concurrently so it doesn't care what order they are in and in most Database situations you shouldn't either.  Is there a reason a CSV must be in exact order?  Most modern databases you would import it too would allow you to query whatever order you want and many will build indexes to support multiple orders.

Comment: Unfortunately, sorting the file was a request coming from me. If I understood you well, it is not quite possible? The people asking me that will finally deal with it, but I just would like to know :)